# declare form_theme once for several forms Twig

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I have three forms on a twig: form1, form2 and form3. 
Is there a way to import my custom theme once?

I mean, now i have this

```
{% form_theme form 'customTwigForms.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form2 'customTwigForms.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form3 'customTwigForms.html.twig' %}
```

and i want somthing like

```
{% form_theme form1, form2, form3 'editDefaultsTwigForms.html.twig' %}
```

i`m using symfony 4.4 and twig v2

Comment: Do you want it just for specific forms? You can do it [globally in configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-all-forms).

Comment: Yes, just for specific forms. I have diferent themes and templates, and use them in different cases. In the twig with this 3 forms there are more forms with other themes